# videojs playlist playbackRate does not persist when new video loads

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have put together a video playlist successfully using videojs and the videojs playlist plugin.  While playing a video, if you change the playback rate from say 1 to 2, when the video auto advances to the next video in the list, the playbackRate defaults back to 1 and you have to readjust it again.  The question is how do you make the playbackRate persist?

Although I can get the playbackRate and set the playbackRate, I can't make it persist.  With the exception of writing it to a hidden div, is there a more elegant solution?

I have the following code:

```
// JavaScript Document

var videoList = [{
  sources: [{
    src: 'http://localhost/gpifmlocal/publichtml/eUFM/1_intro.mp4',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
  poster: ''
  },{
  sources: [{
    src: 'http://localhost/gpifmlocal/publichtml/eUFM/2_UFM_barter.mp4',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
  poster: ''
  },{
  sources: [{
    src: 'http://localhost/gpifmlocal/publichtml/eUFM/3_UFM_goldsmith.mp4',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
  poster: ''
  } ];

var player = videojs(document.querySelector('video'), {
  inactivityTimeout: 0
});

 player.playlist(videoList);

 document.querySelector('.previous').addEventListener('click', function() {

      var playing  = player.playlist.currentItem();

      player.playlist.currentItem(playing -1);
});

document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', function() {

   var playing  = player.playlist.currentItem();
   player.playlist.currentItem(playing +1); 

    });  

  var onlinevideo =document.querySelectorAll('.onlinevideo');

     for(var i=0;i<onlinevideo.length;i++){
     onlinevideo[i].addEventListener('click',videonumber);
     }

 function videonumber(){
  var vid = parseInt($(this).attr('data-vid'));
    if (!player.play()) {
      player.play();
      }else{
      player.playlist.currentItem(vid);

     // var playrate = parseFloat(player.playbackRate());   

      // player.playbackRate(playrate);

 } 
  $(this).css('color','green');

 }

 var endvideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

   endvideo.addEventListener("ended", function() { 

   var playing  = player.playlist.currentItem();

    $('a[data-vid]').each(function() {
    var vid = parseInt($(this).attr('data-vid'))

      if (vid ==playing){
        $(this).css('color','green');
    }
  });

  }, true);


  player.playlist.autoadvance(JSON.parse(0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much apologies, if you dog deep enough, there is a link to all the methods and events in an api: https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist/blob/master/docs/api.md#playlistitem

Therefore to answer my question I simply used:

```
var playrate;
player.on('beforeplaylistitem', function() {
  playrate = player.playbackRate();

  });

 player.on('playlistitem', function() {
   player.playbackRate(playrate);
 });
```

Comment: Good solution!  You should mark this as the best answer, at least until they find a way to persist the rate within the Playlist.